# What are the differences (object size, performance, etc.) between a function that returns a local static and a function that returns a static member?

Tags: c++, static

My derived class needs to provide a function that returns a std::vector& to the caller.

I could declare a static member and initialize it either in the constructor or in the 'global scope' of the CPP file.  I could also declare a local static in the derived function and return it.

The first option has declaration, initialization and return functionality in three separate locations of the code, while the second option consolidates all three elements in the same place.  What are the object size, performance, etc. differences between these approaches?

Edits start here after reading comments through SergeyA.  I am editing the code example of PeterT, adding a sample to show that the constructor utilizes push_back.  So I must admit to SergeyA that initialization does occur in the global scope and as written below, there are four separate locations where the variable s_val appears.

```
//ex.h
#include <vector>
using intVec = std::vector<int>;
struct ex
{
    ex();
    static intVec s_val;
    intVec& getVal();
};

//ex.cpp    
intVec ex::s_val = intVec(5);

ex::ex()
{
    if (s_val.size() == 0) {
        s_val.reserve(5);
        s_val.push_back(1);
        s_val.push_back(4);
        s_val.push_back(0);
        s_val.push_back(2);
        s_val.push_back(3);
    }
    assert(s_val.size() == 5);
}

intVec& ex::getVal()
{
    return s_val;
}
```

I want to modernize and simplify the code to use an initializer list.  It sounds like returning a global static allows me to do that in a clean and efficient manner.  Is this correct ?

```
//ex.h
#include <vector>
using intVec = std::vector<int>;
struct ex
{
    intVec& getVal();
};

//ex.cpp    
static intVec s_val = { 1, 4, 0, 2, 3 };

intVec& ex::getVal()
{
    assert(s_val.size() == 5);
    return s_val;
}
```

Comment: "What are the differences" - Negligible / irrelevant (with an optimizing compiler). Clarity/readability of the code matters *orders of magnitude* more.

Answer (score 1):

A local static will incur the cost of an initialization guard (a mutex lock) on every call to the function. This is due to C++11 guaranteeing thread-safe initialization of statics, which for local statics means access serialization.

A global static (which also includes static class members) does not incur that cost, since global static are initialized before `main()` runs.

You can see the initialization guards in the generated assembly:

https://godbolt.org/z/BzdzvN

Comment: The cost of such lock is neglectable on most modern platforms.

Answer (score 0):

When you do do this

```
//ex.h
#include <vector>
using intVec = std::vector<int>;
struct ex
{
    static intVec s_val;
    intVec& getVal();
};

//ex.cpp

intVec ex::s_val = intVec(5);

intVec& ex::getVal()
{
    return s_val;
}
```

Then the initialization code for instantiating the vector happens before `main()`

But if you do

```
//ex.h
#include <vector>
using intVec = std::vector<int>;
struct ex
{
    intVec& getVal();
};

//ex.cpp
intVec& ex::getVal()
{
    static intVec s_val = intVec(5);
    return s_val;
}
```

Then the initialization of the static variable (the constructor of `std::vector` being called) happens when you call the function for the first time.

<s>This can be an issue in multi-threaded contexts where it can lead to race-conditions, but in this case you're returning a mutable reference to a static `std::vector` so I'm assuming that threading doesn't matter for this specific case anyway.</s> (nvm. see Nikos answer to this question for why that's not longer a concern)

Answer (score 0):

There is some misunderstanding there. If you declare a static member of the class, you can't initialize it in the constructor. You can obviously assign it in the constructor, but it will be assigned whenever a new object will be created (potentially multiple times) which probably doesn't make any sense for most applications.

If you declare a static member, you should either make it a constexpr and initialize in-place, or initialize outside of class definition. The latter exposes you to all the glory of static initialization order fiasco, unless you can guarantee a compile-time initialization for your member.

Function-local static has not issues with initialization order, and have a defined order. However, with function local static you'd pay a **minuscule** price of a branch (predicted) every time you call the function. For most applications, this is not even worth talking about.

Comment: Google Benchmark shows the local static version being twice as slow as the global one.

Comment: @NikosC. SMYC - show me your code and compile switches. This is not supported by my observations.

Comment: [Code](https://pastebin.com/raw/veBZ9mwR), [results](https://pastebin.com/raw/0gDuZ2N5). Switches with GCC 8.3.0: `-std=c++17 -O3 bench.cpp -pthread -lbenchmark`

Comment: Did you just disable the optimizations???

Comment: It's `-O3`. Unless you mean the `DoNotOptimize` wrap, which prevents the compiler from optimizing the expression away. Without that, the global static version is optimized away, making it appear like the local static version is 1000000% slower. Note that this does not disable optimization. It only protects the expression from being deleted by the compiler.

Comment: @NikosC. after examining that more carefully, I agree with those results and I believe they are inline with my answer. We are talking about access price of 0.6 ns vs 0.3 ns. Anything you would be doing with the object itself will likely dwarf those. So yes, minuscule price of 0.3 ns is paid, and yes, not significant for all but the tiniest minority of usage cases.

Comment: @PeterT it was not me who promised it to you.